# code to print first 6 mersenne prime number code?

Tags: java

I am asked to write a method that would display the first six Mersenne prime numbers. I definitely know there is something so wrong but I just can't figure it out. I have this code which does not display anything:

```
public static void printMersennePrimes()
{
    int p = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    int powTwo = 2;
    boolean isPrime = true;

    while(counter <= 6) 
    {
        //determine p is a prime number or not
        for (int m = 2; isPrime; m++) {
            if (m * m > p) {
                isPrime = true;
                break;
            }
            if (p % m == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        //if p is a prime number, test if it equals 2^n-1
        if (isPrime) {
            while(powTwo <= p + 1) {
                powTwo *= 2;
                if(powTwo == p + 1) {
                    System.out.println(p);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        p++;
        powTwo = 2;
    }
}
```

if someone can help me and explain what my problem is, I'll really appreciate that....

Comment: Could you fix your indentation please? I can barely tell what code is in which block.

Comment: I did. if it's still hard to read, please tell me.

Comment: I ran this in a debugger and after it prints 3, p goes to 4, and the for loop never runs because isPrime was set to false and never gets reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had two problems. The first was as Scary Wombat suggested with `break`ing after setting `isPrime` to `true` in the for loop.

Your second problem is that you are not resetting `isPrime` to `true` ever. Once you find a nonprime number, your primality checking for loop never executes since `isPrime` is always `false`. Put `isPrime = true;` as the first line of code of the outer `while` loop, and that should do the trick.

One last thing. Since you start `counter` at `0` and go to `<= 6`, you actually print 7 primes instead of 6. Put `< 6` or `<= 5` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! But I initialized isPrime at first, why that doesn't tell the loop that isPrime is true?

Comment: You initialize `isPrime` outside the loop, so when it gets changed to false inside the loop (when it encounters the first nonprime of 4), it never gets reset, since it is still in the while loop. Your primality checking for loop assumes isPrime is true when it starts when it isn't necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

#### A Method for Testing Primality

I would *start* by extracting the method for testing primality, specifically only test for even and then you can test odd numbers less than or equal to the square root of the value. Something like,

```
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### Only Mersenne Primes

Since we only need the first 6 Mersenne primes we can limit the iteration of values (and *primality* testing) to the Mersenne numbers. Something like,

```
public static void printMersennePrimes() {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 2; counter < 6; i++) {
        int val = (int) Math.pow(2, i) - 1;
        if (isPrime(val)) {
            System.out.printf("2^%d - 1 (%d)%n", i, val);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Which I ran, and got the results specified in the [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) Wikipedia page,

> The first four Mersenne primes M<sub>2</sub> = 3, M<sub>3</sub> = 7, M<sub>5</sub> = 31 and M<sub>7</sub> = 127 were known in antiquity. The fifth, M<sub>13</sub> = 8191, was discovered anonymously before 1461; the next two (M<sub>17</sub> and M<sub>19</sub>) were found by Cataldi in 1588.

Answer (score 0):

Java's Stream API makes these kind of tasks a lot clearer to code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)                                   // For all integers
    .map(i -> (int) Math.pow(2, i) - 1)                              // get the Mersenne style ones
    .filter(i -> IntStream.range(2, i).noneMatch(n -> i % n == 0))   // filter the primes
    .limit(6)                                                        // limit to the first 6
    .forEach(System.out::println);                                   // print them
}
```